# character causing syntax issue with statsmodel

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to fit a linear model to some data using the code below.  I'm getting the error below.  I think the error has an issue with the '%' in the field name.  I have many fields in my data with this naming convention.  Does anyone know how to solve this issue with statsmodel?

code:

```
mod = ols('fieldA%'+'~'+'fieldB',data=smp_df).fit()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-24-9e4f478cefb9>", line 3, in <module>
    mod = ols('fieldA%'+' ~'+'fieldB',data=smp_df).fit()

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 155, in from_formula
    missing=missing)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\formula\formulatools.py", line 65, in handle_formula_data
    NA_action=na_action)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py", line 310, in dmatrices
    NA_action, return_type)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py", line 165, in _do_highlevel_design
    NA_action)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py", line 70, in _try_incr_builders
    NA_action)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\patsy\build.py", line 689, in design_matrix_builders
    factor_states = _factors_memorize(all_factors, data_iter_maker, eval_env)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\patsy\build.py", line 354, in _factors_memorize
    which_pass = factor.memorize_passes_needed(state, eval_env)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py", line 474, in memorize_passes_needed
    subset_names = [name for name in ast_names(self.code)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py", line 474, in <listcomp>
    subset_names = [name for name in ast_names(self.code)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py", line 105, in ast_names
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(code)):

  File "C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    CIM_ID_SALES %
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can use Q patsy built-in to escape the character. check docs https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtins-reference.html

Comment: You could try mod = ols("Q('fieldA%') ~ fieldB") ,data=smp_df).fit()